# Finding the name of the maximum value for each category

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a groupby object that shows the total price brand wise and state wise of different car brands:

```py
grouped_a = cars_data.groupby(['brand','state']) 
grouped_a['price'].sum()
```

what function can I use that returns the brand associated with the highest total price in each state? I have tried looping throug the groupby object but it doesn't work.

Comment: What does `grouped_a['price'].idxmax()` return?

Comment: it returns the state and brand of the highest price of the whole dataset, not the highest total price in each state.

Comment: It should return the indexes of the max rows @Cdf, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can groupby to get the max total per state per brand, then merge to find the brand(s) with the highest total.  Note you may have more than one brand that has the same total.  Here's one way to do it:

```
row1list = ['Ford', 'California', 100]
row2list = ['Toyota', 'California', 200]
row3list = ['Toyota', 'California', 300]
cars_data = pd.DataFrame([row1list, row2list, row3list], columns=['brand', 'state', 'price'])

df_total_by_br_st = cars_data.groupby(['brand', 'state'], as_index=False).agg({'price': sum})
df_max_by_st = df_total_by_br_st.groupby('state', as_index=False).agg({'price': max})

df_max_by_st = df_max_by_st.rename(columns={'price': 'max_price'})

df_total_by_br_st = df_total_by_br_st.merge(df_max_by_st, on='state', how='left')
df_max_brand_by_state = df_total_by_br_st[df_total_by_br_st['price'] == df_total_by_br_st['max_price']]

print(df_max_brand_by_state)
#    brand       state  price  max_price
# 1  Toyota  California    500        500
```

Answer (score 0):

`idxmax()` gives you the row indexes with maximum values.

```
>>> cars_data
   price      state brand
0     10  emergency    on
1     20  emergency   ing
2     15     trance    on
3     12     trance   ing
>>> max_price_rows = cars_data.groupby(['state'])['price'].idxmax()
>>> max_price_rows
state
emergency    1
trance       2
Name: price, dtype: int64
```

So rows 1 and 2, i.e. with prices `20` and `15`.

If you want the max per state, then pass that result to `.loc[]`:

```
>>> cars_data.loc[max_price_rows]
   price      state brand
1     20  emergency   ing
2     15     trance    on
```